LINK EMPTY TO TRACK WORKS WITH AN OFFSET
I am linking empties to track markers to adjust the camera position and sort out the tracking scene, but the empties appear to have an offset in the location - they are NOT placed in the origin of the marker, but in the middle of the bottom edge of it. How to sort that?

You are sure the camera perspective is exactly perpendicular to the image, and the image isn’t offset vertically, yes?

the image is a video and it follows the camera according to the SETUP TRACKING SCENE command

Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.

Did you try enabling/disabling the Render Undistorded ? Are all points offset a few pixels downwards, or is it a radial offset (origin at center of image) ? You didn't give much information to help you.
